# R Applying vector to vector function for matrix to matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector, apply

I am using distHaversine, which takes two points and gives a distance, i.e.

> distHaversine(c(35,-75),c(35.1,-74.9)) prints:
>   [1] 11501.11

I have two matricies, A and B that are (m by 2) and (n by 2), i.e. A has m points and B has n points. How can I use distHaversine on A and B to get a m x n matrix of distances?

Comment: You have to mention the package that has `distHaversine` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using `distHaversine` of `geosphere` package.
If so, this could be of your help:

```
t(apply(a, 1, function(x)distHaversine(x, b)))
```